# Riddle of Markburg

Tags: cipher, visual, story

In a school located 3 kilometers below the city of Markburg. Alexander and his friend, Schim, talking about funny jokes but 1 hour later, Schim created a mysterious message with his pencil, coloring pencils, and a piece of paper. Schim gave Alexander a mysterious message and he doesn't know so he takes it to his mother's home for decrypting purpose. Alexander tried to decrypt the message but unsuccesfully, remained undecrypted and undone.

Image:
[image: Lmfao]

What did the message say?

Comment: Hi welcome to Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answers:

> The "Korean kingdom that's lived until 10th century" is the Silla (though the more accurate way to actually write as it is sounded in Korean is Shinla, 신라) kingdom/dynasty. #koreanhistory. As a side note, I'm surprised you know this, are you Korean?

And

> Um the Jesus is called a ? is pretty broad. He's known as Christ, Messiah, the Son of God, the Lamb, etc. Clarification please?

And

> I have no idea what a "papatoolie" is. Google search shows some eBay seller.

And

> What is a joke-a-wee? A dodo's a bird... maybe like the Joker and Penguin from *Batman*?

Comment: you misread your second clue.  There is no "is".